How to create a datadog gauge metric in python Lambda?
We have a Lambda written in Python, and we use datadog-lambda library to report metrics to datadog.
Is there a way to create a gauge metric using the above library?

Use datalog_lambda.metric to submit custom metric to Datadog.
Lil' example:
from datadog_lambda.metric import lambda_metric

lambda_metric('metric_name', 1, tags=['tag1:value1', 'tag2'])


tnx, but what defines this metric as gauge?

@Chedva In my example, the lambda_metric function is used to submit a custom metric to Datadog. The type of the metric (gauge, count, rate, etc.) is not explicitly defined in the function call, but it's determined by how you use the metric in Datadog.
By default, when you submit a custom metric using lambda_metric, Datadog treats it as a gauge. If you want to change the type of the metric, you can do so in the Datadog web interface.
